# Can't run my app with -variant=release, crashes immediately

Tags: react-native, release

I'm creating a fairly small app, 3 screens using simple components such as Flatlist, Image and Searchbar. It runs nicely except when I try to test with --variant=release.

I did the signing process and I can confirm this part works as I've deployed my app in Google Beta successfully (only to see the test report from Google showing my app crashed on all simulators).

I've also tried everything I could find on Google (cleaning, reset cache, upgrading everything to last version, even starting my project from scratch and just copy pasting my src folder in).

Here's my package.json, in case something's wrong with my dependencies I couldn't see :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-gallery-swiper": "^1.23.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-hooks": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Here's an extract of the logcat file when I start the app :

```
10-22 10:40:51.265 32285 32285 E elevenelevenap: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
10-22 10:40:51.340  1817  1921 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-22 10:40:51.341  1817  1921 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-22 10:40:51.822  1817  1817 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{b55b6c0 token=Token{4cb0043 ActivityRecord{43741f2 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t5}}})/@0x2af8cf8 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
10-22 10:40:51.823  1817  1817 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{b55b6c0 token=Token{4cb0043 ActivityRecord{43741f2 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t5}}})/@0x2af8cf8 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
10-22 10:40:51.823  1817  1817 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{470f541 token=Token{8241428 ActivityRecord{21c524b u0 com.elevenelevenapp/.MainActivity t95}}})/@0xf0a643b - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
10-22 10:40:51.823  1817  1817 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{470f541 token=Token{8241428 ActivityRecord{21c524b u0 com.elevenelevenapp/.MainActivity t95}}})/@0xf0a643b - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
10-22 10:40:51.840  1817  1817 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{b55b6c0 token=Token{4cb0043 ActivityRecord{43741f2 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t5}}})/@0x2af8cf8 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
10-22 10:40:51.840  1817  1817 E Layer   : [Surface(name=AppWindowToken{470f541 token=Token{8241428 ActivityRecord{21c524b u0 com.elevenelevenapp/.MainActivity t95}}})/@0xf0a643b - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
10-22 10:40:52.105 32285 32310 E ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm.hot.accept')
10-22 10:40:52.107 32285 32310 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.elevenelevenapp, PID: 32285
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm.hot.accept'), stack:
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@383:349
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@6:58
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: v@2:1474
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: d@2:876
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: global code@968:4
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime: 
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:71)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:371)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:150)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:26)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:225)
10-22 10:40:52.109 32285 32311 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
10-22 10:40:52.174  1799  2450 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
10-22 10:40:52.174  1799  2450 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
10-22 10:40:52.197  2038  2142 E InputDispatcher: channel '1977922 com.elevenelevenapp/com.elevenelevenapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

As you can see it shows a few errors but so far I couldn't trace them back to something I could work on, hence asking you guys some help, I'm quite desperate.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need application to add inside the tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true".`

like this:

```
    <application
    ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      ...
    >

   ...
</application>
```

Let me know if this works for, though im kind of late right now

Comment: Thank you Karan :) While this might have helped, I found my solution some time ago. It was a line that I had in my entry JS file `module.hot.accept(() => { ... }` which was causing the error, as pointed out in the logcat file extract I attached in my question `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm.hot.accept')`. Cheers